# how do we get this output C++

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
for(i=0,j=0;i<5,j<25;i++,j++);
    cout<<i <<" "<<j;
```

And I don't know why it outputs `25 25`. I really don't understand why its getting the value 25 in `i` and `j`. Can any one please explain me why it is reaching value 25 from the second condition? Is this the problem of checking the two condition in one for loop?

Comment: What output would you want/expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the effect of the [comma operator](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4db.html). This means it *ignores* the first argument of the test and returns the 2nd for the test result.

Since you have semicolon (`;`) at the end of your loop

```
 for(i=0,j=0;i<5,j<25;i++,j++);
                              ^
```

your for-loop executes "silently" all the way through (only considering the `j<25` condition) and when it is done, the value for both variables is `25`.

If you want to see the output while the loop is executing to verify this, remove the `;` from the end of the `for` statement.

If you wanted to terminate the loop based on the values of both `i < 5` and `j < 25` you probably want to use the `&&` (and) operator.

Comment: ya that ; was intentional .. ok now i got it , operator is like || operator right

Comment: @RashmiAM ok .. just checking :) Usually, in that case, the convention is to put the `;` on a line by itself to make that intention explicit (too many times the `;` happens by mistake, force of habit putting a semi-colon at the end of each statement :) .. in any case, I hope the rest of my answer explains the reason for your output.

Comment: I wonder why nobody mentioned that unless there's some other code inside loop's body that also increments `j`, this kind of condition is completely unnecessary. `i < 5` would do just fine.

Comment: @jrok Actually, the way the loop is right now, it's not necessary either :) It would be easier just to say `i = j = 25;` .. I think this was an unintentional mistake/misunderstanding about how the comma operator works. I bet OP was just exploring the language - I often learn by just trying out things and seeing if the behavior matches what I expect.

Comment: I meant `i < 5 && j < 25` specifically, agreed otherwise.

Comment: Small typo in the answer: it should be `j<25` instead of `i<25`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because how comma operator works in c.

`i = (a,b);`

this will assign `b` to `i`. as in your case `i<5,j<25` `j<25` is used as the check  and there is no impact of value of `i` on the loop.

I Hope what you want to achieve is :

```
i<5&&j<25
```

If you are expecting the output to be `5,5`.

If you want to print output for each iteration then remove the semicolon at the end of for.

Comment: Are you sure this is an useful alternative?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Are you sure it wouldn't be more efficient to directly say "You are second-guessing the OP's desires without anything to go by"?

Answer (score 0):

The `,` operator is one the ignores the first argument and returns the second. Thus only the second condition applies. What you need is `&&`.

Comment: I agree, up until the last sentence. Are you sure `&&` solves the problem?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, what do you think OP expects from that loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you meant the loop should run until `i < 5` and `j < 25` is true. here is the code for that using `&&` operator.

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
for(i=0,j=0; i<5 && j < 25; i++,j++);
cout<<i <<" "<<j;
```

Here both i and j will be 5.

If you use OR(`||`) operator where both i and j will be 25 as both are getting incremented in the for loop until both the condition becomes false.

If you want i to be 5 and j to be 25, better write two loops or by the following code.

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
for(i=0,j=0; j < 25; j++)
{
    if( i < 5 )
    {
        i++;
    }
}
cout<<i <<" "<<j;
```